# Safari iCloud tabs don't sync between macOS and iOS. How do I debug this?

Tags: icloud, safari

The problem is, history DOES sync, but tabs don't. There was a period where a stale list of tabs did show up, both on my iPhone and on my MacBook, but that didn't update. After toggling the safari thing in the iCloud settings on iOS and macOS, the tab list stopped showing up at all.
Now safari is enabled in the settings and the history syncs, but open tabs don't!

Any pointers on how to debug iCloud?
How does it actually sync safari stuff?

[edit]
Forgot to mention, bookmarks sync too.
It's just tabs that don't.

Comment: Are your Safari windows private (windows started with File>New Private Window)? Only tabs in regular (non-private) windows are synced.

Comment: @jaume sorry for the delay, no they are not private windows. Forgot to mention bookmarks sync too, just tabs don't, and they used to.

Comment: At this point I'm looking more for pointers on how this whole thing works. iCloud seems kind of opaque, couldn't find off hand descriptions of how the different services work.

Comment: I also have this currently. iOS 12 and macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra.

Comment: I experience the same issue on both latest versions of iOS 13 and macOS 15